# Expected Value in modified Let-it-Ride

Tags: probability, game-theory

Let-it-Ride is a casino table game which you can read about here: 
http://wizardofodds.com/games/let-it-ride/

This page also has expected values done for the normal game!

In my modified version, each player receives 4 cards and must discard one before the dealer reveals a community card. They may still pull back their first bet after they have discarded. They may pull their second bet as usual.

How is the player doing in this version of the game assuming they make an optimal discard?

A hand like Kh Ks Qs Js, should we break the pair or not? 
The problem seems easy enough just taking the probabilities of being dealt each 4 card possibility and combining it with the expected value payout already calculated. I am not sure how to combine these two things with the discard.